# Помогите найти ошибку в head

Tags: html

Всем привет, в общем дали проект на верстку. Руководитель вечно чем то недоволен, говорит опять говнокод пишешь. В хеде просто треш, но при этом ничего не говорит где и в каком месте, что неправильно. Помогите найти ошибку!(если она есть)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<footer>
<script src="/js/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/owlcarousel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: где твой body?приятель

Comment: И что у тебя футоре делают скрипты?

Comment: @Air а что, это запрещено?

Comment: Можно ещё все подключаемые библиотеки css и js скомпилировать в один файл и минифицировать при необходимости.

Comment: В самом head-е я ничего криминального не вижу. Возможно (но тут решать вам) стоит спросить у других работников вашей фирмы или у самого начальника разъяснение. Общение с другими разработчиками в фирме помогает и расслабиться и наладить контакт, и в развитии личных возможностей в программировании.

Comment: попробуйте сначала скрипты подгружать все, потом стили, или в другом порядке, что бы было более структурировано.

Comment: Body здесь не указан, я просто вырезал кусок кода. В том числе и футер. Вообще он есть. Однако претензий своего руководителя по поводу head'a, так и не понял. Дал мысль в плане порядка подключения css и js. И все равно не понимаю какой в этом смысл, если необходимые css и js работают

Comment: @Дмитрий ну если руководитель не собирается объяснять - значит и париться не стоит. Либо есть конструктивная критика, либо пуская помалкивает. А гадать нам, что **конкретно ему** не нравится не имеет смысла

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Так именно про это я и говорю, что нам гадать смысла особого нету. Хотя если бы были явные недоработки... Но тут их нету.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин вообще это было сообщение для ТС ;-)  похоже движок SO задел всех Дмитриев в топике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Document checking completed. **No errors** or warnings to show.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 <title>Document</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  
  </head>
<body> 
 <footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/owlcarousel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых есть очень много online сервисов проверки html кода, javascript кода и css кода на валидность - можно пользоваться ими, они покажут ошибки (поищите в гугле).

Например, 
http://csslint.net/ (для css)

Касательно вашего кода, то что сразу бросается в глаза

1) тег `</footer>` 2 раза

2) внутри `<footer></footer>` размещается визуальная информация, а у вас только подключение скриптов, в итоге  излишен

3) у вас отсутствует тег `<body></body>` в котором и должен был бы находиться `<footer>` и другая визуальная информация (то что увидит пользователь)

как я понял, вы привели только раздел `<head>` сайта. Удалите из него `<footer>` - скорее всего он приводит к тому, что скрипты размещенные в нем не будут запускаться (может и будут, но не стоит теги из `<body>`) сувать куда попало)

Comment: кто сказал, что в футере нельзя подключать скрипты?

Comment: никто, разве я где-то написал что в теги нельзя вставлять скрипты?

в данном случае есть head, нет body, в footer только(!) скрипты - вопрос - зачем тогда footer? который еще и не в body (разве что css его визуально во что-то формирует), в любом случае есть лишний закрывающий тег

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте тайтл. Скорее всего заказчик хочет получить от вас не только верстку сайта, а еще и возможность продвигать сайт. Отсутствие title, подключение фавикона и meta тегов "og-" его насторожило. В добавок учтите также то, что напишут в ответе другие помощники на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все проще ему не нравится последовательность подключений css и js. Хед ещё в работе, в тайтле пока ничего не будет все на стадии верстки. Всем спасибо за помощь и разумные варианты проблем в его голове.